# @media print , div and header overlap

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I just want add header for every pages. So i use @media print. This is my code

```
@media screen {
    div#parent {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media print {
    div#parent {
        position:fixed;
        display:block;
        top:0;
    }
}
```

The problem is header have overlaped with every page

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space between the content and your header. I don't know your html structure, but if you have something like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>

<body>
    <div class="head">
        <!-- Your header here -->
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <!-- Your page content here -->
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

You need to add some `margin-top` or `padding-top` to the class `.content`, and it should work fine:

**CSS**

```
.content {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. but doing so only adds a header to the first page. because many pages share only one div.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: my problem is give every page set a header.now just the first page have effect

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `include` method that `php` gives us.

Imagine you have following structure:

```
app|
   | header.html
   | index.php
```

In your header, you will have the header you are using right now, and in the index.php, you will have to call that file. You can use `<?php  include "header.html"; ?>`

Your index.php, should look like this:

```
<body>

    <?php include "header.html"; ?>

    <div class="content">
        <!-- Page Content Here -->
    </div>

</body>
```